# Is there a way to display dynamic row count in Excel?

Tags: excel

Simple formatting question, is there a way to write the number of rows dynamically when calling ranges of cells? For example, on Google Sheets, the data range I call is D2:D, which selects the entire range of data. When I try to put the same thing into Excel, the formula breaks. Is there a similar substitute for this in Excel or is it not possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to reference D2 to the last populated cell in column D,

```
d$2:index(d:d, max(iferror(match(1e99, d:d), 0), iferror(match("zzz", d:d), 0)))
'numbers or dates,
d$2:index(d:d, match(1e99, d:d))
'text,
d$2:index(d:d, match("zzz", d:d))
```

Comment: Is Microsoft listening?  Sounds like =lastrow(D:D) or maybe =bottom(D:D) to me.

Comment: They did add =TRANSPOSE() recently, which was indeed helpful

Comment: Apologies, they were numbers. I'll clarify what data types I'm using next time.

Comment: I've added specifics for all numbers/dates or all text.